# Movie Shooting Mode, Not Supported

Tags: camera, sony, sony-camera-api

I'm developing an application with the Sony Camera Remote API, using the a6000 as a test device. When calling `startRecMode` I get the following error message on the camera - *The movie shooting mode of this application is not supported on this device*

According to Sony's documentation the a6000 should support movie recording. Calling `getAvailableApiList` upon this device returns `startRecMode` as an available api method.

Downloading the PlayMemories Mobile app allows me to connect to this device, but starting record mode from my mobile device shows the same error message on the camera.

How can I start recording on the a6000 using the Sony Camera Remote API?

Comment: Looks like a few others have had the same issue - http://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3691430

Comment: Thanks for the downvote

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are running the latest firmware for the camera.  You can get it here: http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/swu-download.pl?mdl=ILCE6000&upd_id=10403&os_group_id=5.

Comment: Thanks Marlin, but it looks like I have the most recent version of the firmware installed. I'll try reinstalling to see if that helps.

Comment: Ok, if that doesn't work another thing to check is that your camera function is in "Remote Shooting" mode before you try to make the call to startRecMode.  See the setCameraFunction method in the documentation for more details.